# Record audio and save data using an outputstream

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avcapturesession

We are trying to record audio from the iPhone using an internal or external microphone.
Due to some restrictions, we need to save the data using an output stream.

So what I've tried to do is use the **`AVCaptureSession`** and use the **`AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`** to capture **CMSampleBuffer** and turn that into a buffer that we can use to save the data to a file.

But without any luck. Is there anybody that can point me in the right direction?

I'm not sure how to turn the **`CMSampleBuffer`** into a Data buffer.

Thanks.